# Grunt Serve - returns ruby errors

Tags: ruby, macos, gruntjs, yeoman

I recently wiped my mac, and am in the process of reinstalling all of my dev environments - when installing node/npm/yeoman/grunt/bower - I have a test proj, and on 'grunt serve' the build gets through several steps then errors out.

```
matt-macbook:testNew mattbtay$ grunt serve
```

Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

```
Running "copy:styles" (copy) task


Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2014-03-02 04:05:29 UTC)
loading tasks   8ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 40%
copy:styles    11ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 55%
Total 20ms
    Warning: /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/compass:23:in `<main>' Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

Execution Time (2014-03-02 04:05:22 UTC)
concurrent:server  8.7s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 100%
Total 8.7s

Comment: Not sure as we cannot see your Gruntfile, but it looks like you are missing the compass library. See the [compass site](http://compass-style.org/install/) for help installing the ruby gem.

Comment: That is what I thought (at first)

    matt-macbook:testNew mattbtay$ gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

celluloid (0.15.2)
CFPropertyList (2.2.0)
chunky_png (1.3.0)
compass (0.12.2)
ffi (1.9.3)
fssm (0.2.10)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
listen (2.4.1)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.3)
rubygems-update (2.2.2)
sass (3.3.0.rc.5)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
timers (1.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to update the version of sass

sudo gem uninstall sass
sudo gem install sass
sudo gem install compass

(I installed Compass again, and every thing looks to be good. May have been an incompatible version of SASS???)